# What covers larger territory: advection fog or frontal fog?

Tags: meteorology, scale

Between [Frontal fog](http://glossary.ametsoc.org/wiki/Frontal_fog) and [Advection fog](http://glossary.ametsoc.org/wiki/Advection_fog) which covers larger territory ?

If it's possible, provide some source of information as a proof

Comment: Hi Nikita, welcome to Earth SE.  Can you please [edit](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/posts/19147/edit) your question?  As it is now, it is not clear what you are asking and your question might be closed as unclear.

Comment: @gerrit OP is probably coming from a aviation background. In which case legitimate question

Comment: It looks a homework question (well disguised)but a topic not covered on this site.